# Do I need an Apostille on my Romanian Birth Certificate for use in Portugal?

Tags: residency, portugal

My situation is:

- I am an EU citizen, born in Romania
- I am living in Portugal, with my residence certificate already established
- My partner (co-habitating > 2 years) is an American citizen, born in the USA.
- She is applying for her residency in Portugal, which requires both of our birth certificates.
- I have my Romanian birth certificate already, in the Romanian language only

My understanding is:

- My partner's birth certificate needs to be translated to Portuguese and Apostille'd.
- My birth certificate needs to be translated to Portuguese.

My question is:

- Does my birth certificate need to be Apostille'd?

I base my question on [this website](https://blog.newlandchase.com/european-union-apostille-no-longer-required-on-public-documents-issued-by-eu-member-states) which states:

> Under the Public Documents Regulation (EU) 2016/1191, effective 16 February 2019, an apostille (authenticity stamp) is no longer required when presenting public documents issued by the authorities of one European Union (EU) member state to the authorities of another EU member state.

However it also says:

> However, the implementation of the new rules may take varying amounts of time at different authorities in different member states.

This leads me to be uncertain what the situation is in Portugal currently.

Comment: You need to ask the authority you will be providing the birth certificate to. My instinct says an Apostille will not be necessary but you must contact them to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I did not have to - SEF accepted the birth certificate along with the certified translation, without an Apostille.